# Schengen visa appeal result when I don't need to use it anymore

Tags: schengen-visas

I booked a stall in an exhibition for 24-25 June 2017.

I applied for a visa which was refused and when I did appeal, German embassy said that processing time is 3 months. Now the exhibition is already over and the embassy still hasn't responded.

What decision can be expected from German embassy in this situation?

I visited Schengen previously in 2003, 2011 and 2014.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I edited your question to make it hopefully clearer, please make sure I haven't changed the sense. I understand that 3 months since your appeal haven't passed yet? What country are you from? The exhibition was the only reason for you to go to Germany, right?

Comment: @Kuba great edit. I voted to approved (one more vote is needed). Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know enough about Germany to answer but in another Schengen country, what could happen – assuming there is any merit to the appeal – is that the court invalidates the initial decision but the consulate immediately refuses again, citing another reason (namely the lack of purpose for the trip, now that the exhibition is finished). Other possibilities include simply rejecting the appeal (that's what they do most of the time anyway) and finding that there is no need to take a decision anymore.